# Assigning blank value to a DateTime filed

Tags: c#, xml

i have written a Linq to Xml query, to create entities from xml, i have a DateTime field in the xml which can possibly be blank, and i need to assign the same blank to the field in entity, i am getting an error "String not recognized as a DateTime"

XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Sample.xml");

```
        var _pndList =
               from plist in
                   xDocument.Descendants("HEADER")
               select new PND()
               {
                   DeliveryDate =
                       DateTime.ParseExact(Convert(plist, "DELIVERYDATE"), "yyyyMMdd",
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None),
                   LoadClosed =
                       DateTime.ParseExact(Convert(plist, "LOADCLOSEDDATETIME"), "yyyyMMddhhmmss",
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None),
                   TrailerId = Convert(plist, "TRAILERID"),
                   TripAndRouteId = Convert(plist, "TRIPROUTEID"),
                   StoreCode = plist.Ancestors("STORE").Attributes().First().Value,
                   Product =
                       (from mlist in
                            plist.Ancestors("STORE").Descendants("RECORD")
                        select new PreNotifiedProduct()
                        {
                            DepotCode = Convert(plist, "DEPOTCODE"),
                            MU = Convert(mlist, "MU"),
                            CaseOrUnitQuantity =
                                System.Convert.ToInt32("0" + Convert(mlist, "NOOFCASES")),
                            OuterCaseHeight =
                                System.Convert.ToInt32("0" +
                                                       Convert(mlist, "OUTERCASEHEIGHT")),
                            OuterCaseLength =
                                System.Convert.ToInt32("0" +
                                                       Convert(mlist, "OUTERCASELENGTH")),
                            OuterCaseWidth =
                                System.Convert.ToInt32("0" + Convert(mlist, "OUTERCASEWIDTH")),
                            ProductCode = Convert(mlist, "TPNB"),
                            UnitsPerCase =
                                System.Convert.ToInt32("0" + Convert(mlist, "UNITSPERCASE")),
                            UseByDate =
                                DateTime.ParseExact(Convert(plist, "LOADCLOSEDDATETIME"),
                                                    "yyyyMMddhhmmss",
                                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                    DateTimeStyles.None)
                        }).ToList()
               };
    }
```

In the Entity PreNotifiedProduct() UseByDate is of DateTime

Comment: I guess you will have to check if the element is empty or not, if empty then maybe set it to `DateTime.MinValue` (Coz `DateTime` doesn't have anything as blank, the closest would be to make it nullable type and rely on the null as blank value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to set UseByDate as type of "DateTime?" making it nullable.

Then you may have to write in some logic to test to see if it's a valid date.  Perhaps write a function like this.

```
    static DateTime? TestDate(string date)
    {
        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParse("", out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `Nullable(T)` `DateTime`, `DateTime?` or substitute `null` for `DateTime.MinValue` when you cannot.

I would advise against using `MinValue` if you are using some kind of Database backed storage since you will need to ensure the proper precision on the database type so they will match.

```
private static DateTime? TryParseDateTime(string dateTime)
{
    DateTime result;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime,
                                  "yyyyMMddhhmmss",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  DateTimeStyles.None,
                                  out result)
           ? result
           : null;
}
```

Usage:

```
UseByDate = TryParseDateTime(Convert(plist, "LOADCLOSEDDATETIME"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` cannot be blank or null. You can either use `DateTime.MinValue` (default) or change it to `DateTime?` which is nullable and can be then set to null.

You should also use `DateTime.TryParse` if there is a possibility that the string won't be convertable to DateTime. If blank value is the only exception, you can check for that before trying to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the datevalue is blank or not,
if it is blank then dont convert it.

You can use ternary operator to avoid such errors